# Do I need to set addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority for each sprite I want to detect?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i want to detect which sprite has been touched.
if I do :

```
auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create(); 
listener->setSwallowTouches(true);   
listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchBegan, this);
listener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchMoved, this);
listener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchEnded, this);
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener->clone(), mySprite);
```

and then in my touch method I do:

```
bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(Touch* touch, Event* event)
auto spriteBlock = static_cast<Block*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
```

the sprite is detected fine.

the problem is I have like 20 sprites on the layer and I need to be able to detect them all 
do I need to set

```
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener->clone(), mySprite);
```

for each sprite?

Answer (score 5):

No, you do not need add eventListener to all sprites.

You need an event listener for the parent node of the sprites.

Try this:

```
bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(Touch *touch, Event *event) {
    Node *parentNode = event->getCurrentTarget();
    Vector<Node *> children = parentNode->getChildren();
    Point touchPosition = parentNode->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch);
    for (auto iter = children.rbegin(); iter != children.rend(); ++iter) {
        Node *childNode = *iter;
        if (childNode->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(touchPosition)) {
            //childNode is the touched Node
            //do the stuff here
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It is iterate in reverse order because you will touch the sprite with the highest z-index in place (if they overlapping).

Hope, this help.

Comment: I don't know it is the cleanest and the most elegant way, but it is worked for me several times, and it can handle touch on sprite when it is moving (in a running animation). I used it in a hidden object game and it's worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You have to add an eventlistener to each sprite 
and to detect the touches on each 
you have to add this in the touch began function

```
bool OwlStoryScene0::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event) {
        cocos2d::Touch *touched = (Touch *) touch;
        Point location = touched->getLocationInView();
        location = Director::getInstance()->convertToGL(location);
        auto target = static_cast<Sprite*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
        Point locationInNode = target->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());
        Size s = target->getContentSize();
        Rect rect = Rect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
        if (rect.containsPoint(locationInNode)  && target == SPRITE) {
            //DoSomething
        }
        else if (rect.containsPoint(locationInNode) && target == SPRITE) {
            //DoSomething
        }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this works for you